# Error with Android Studio while using Facebook Audience Network

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, ads, facebook-audience-network

I have tried to put Facebook ads in my application, which is earlier works with Google Admob ads. But while adding this line in my gradle file makes errors. `compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+'`. I have also tried with the specified versions. But same errors.

Main error is

> can't resolve Symbol R

I also tried clean, rebuild and Sync Project with Gradle file. But no response.
I have updated my Google play services, and Google Respirotory. 
Here is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.application"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 15
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':businessApp')
    compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+'
}
```

I can successfully build the gradle if I remove this line

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+'
```

There is no other errors in My app. If I need to change anything in Android studio to use Facebook Audience Network, or any other requirements?

Answer (score 0):

After adding this dependency , sync your project and then click on Build-->Clean Project